# How are `and` and `or` statements in Python different with each other?

Tags: python

If you look at this:-

```
>>>a = "hello"
>>>b = "world"
>>>print a and b 
world
>>>print b and a
hello
```

and this:-

```
>>>a = "hello"
>>>b = "world"
>>>print a or b 
hello
>>>print b or a
world
```

Both are almost similar. So how are they different?

Comment: The last one is a typo, isn't it? To get that output, it should be `print b or a`.

Comment: Yes. Sorry. Gonna edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `or` and `and` operators *short-circuit*. They return early when the outcome is a given.

For `or` that means that if the first expression is `True`, then there is no point in looking at the second expression as it doesn't matter:

```
>>> 'a' or 'b'
'a'
>>> False or 'b'
'b'
```

The same goes for `and`, but only when the first value evaluates to `False`; in that case the expression is *always* going to evaluate to `False` whatever the second expression is going to come to:

```
>>> False and 'b'
False
>>> 'a' and 'b'
'b'
```

See [Boolean expressions](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations):

> The expression `x and y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is false, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.
>
> The expression `x or y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is true, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.